# There is a warning that I can't solve for an accumulated list

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
from itertools import accumulate
import operator

e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
acc = accumulate(e)
print(e)
print(list(acc))
acc = accumulate(e, func=operator.mul)  # here
print(list(acc))
f = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 9, 8, 10]
acc = accumulate(f, func=max)
print(f)
print(list(acc))
```

The code is running properly, but there is this warning:

```
Unexpected type(s):(list[int], (args: tuple[Any, ...], kwargs: dict[str, Any]) -> Any)Possible type(s):(Iterable[int], None)(Iterable[int], (Any, int) -> Any)(Iterable[int], (int, int) -> int | None)
```

The indicated sequence is highlighted in yellow in the code, so that's the problem. I think the problem is related to the way the "operator" module works.

I tried to solve it myself in several ways, but nothing worked. I know the code works, but I can't ignore that warning. So what is the solution?

Comment: what were (at least some of) the several ways you tried to remove the warning?

Comment: 1. I tried to replace the variables "e" and "acc" with new ones, believing that the fact that I printed them before as a list or that I modified them changed their nature (I'm a beginner :)).

Comment: 2. I used this code: 
'import operator
from itertools import accumulate
from typing import Callable, List

e: List[int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
acc = accumulate(e)
print(e)
print(list(acc))
acc = accumulate(e, func=operator.mul)
print(list(acc))
f: List[int] = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 9, 8, 10]
acc = accumulate(f, func=max)
print(f)
print(list(acc))'

Comment: code doesn't render in comments. I recommend using the edit button to include that information in the question

Comment: FWIW, I ran this code in Python 3.11.4 without any warnings raised